# Selecting all spans and assigning a style.color value from an array usingn DOM selector

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom, selector

I'm doing The Web Developer Bootcamp by Colt Steele and got stuck on a challenge.

My task is to select all spans, iterate over them and assign each one of the colors from the colors array.

**My solution is:**

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:
const lettersList = document.querySelectorAll('span');


for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
   lettersList.forEach((letter) => {
       letter.style.color = "colors[i]";
   });
         }
```

My idea is to use a for loop to iterate the values of the colors array (stop the loop upon reaching the last element).
Nested inside the for loop is the forEach function that will execute the function `letter.style.color = "colors[i]"` that will assign the value of the iterated colors array to each value of the selectorAll span.

Can you spot my mistake?

Comment: _Can you spot my mistake?_ What are the quotes around `colors[i]` for? Just take them out and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

"colors[i]" is a string that will not be interpretted by javascript. Remove the quotes. Also, you don't need both loops. You can access the index in your [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop as the second argument:

```
   lettersList.forEach((letter, i) => {
       letter.style.color = colors[i];
   });
```

Here's a snippet that demonstrates - also taking into account that your array of colors might not be the same length as the number of spans.

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:
const lettersList = document.querySelectorAll('span');
lettersList.forEach((letter, i) => {
  let index = i < colors.length ? i : i % colors.length
  console.log(index)
  letter.style.color = colors[index];
});
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
<span>Color me</span>
```

Comment: What happens if you have more spans than colors?

Comment: Can you explain the code? How does it access the index of colors when the forEach function is only assigned to lettersList not colors?

The letter parameter is for the values of each elements in the lettersList array right?
Does it mean that i there is the index of lettersList - which will be the same as the index of colors array?

Comment: @Tim - good point. updated. SkyCowie - You can use either the array's length or the #span's length in your iterator. I chose the span's length but it's arbitrary. As Tim mentioned, you should account for an overage on either (more spans than colors or visa versa) - so I added in a line to show how to account for that (using the % modulus) - does that answer your question? I updated my answer